# Can I conclude that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are negative?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $M$ and any positive vector $V$, if I prove that all entries in $MV$ are negative, can I conclude that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are negative?

If yes, how to prove it? or I suppose this lemma has been proved in the book "Matrix iterative analysis", which chapter I can refer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that all eigenvalues are real?

Comment: All eigenvalues are real. or the question can be: Can I conclude that the real parts of all the eigenvalues of M are negative?

Comment: No. For example, take M=[[-1,-2],[-2,-1]]. Then M satisfies the condition, but it has eigenvalues -3 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

No. The matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\ -1&0\end{array}\right)$$
satisfies your condition but one eigenvalue is $1$. (This matrix reflects in the line $x_1=-x_2$).